# Best way to parse all occurrences of a function within a set of files

Tags: php, regex

Let's say we have a function,

```
dosomething(string $text) : string
```

And suppose that we want to programmatically find and list all occurrences of this function within a project with arguments. Given that $text could be any string, how would we do this?

I was thinking about using a regex, such as the pattern

```
dosomething([^)]+)
```

in order to search to the trailing ), but $text could be a string such as "lorem ipsum (but with this)", and that would match prematurely. Searching for " or ' seems to not work either, as we could have a variable

```
dosomething($string)
```

instead of a string as an argument. What would be the best way to go about this?

Comment: What do you want to if the argument is a variable instead of a string? Ignore it? Take the name of the variable?

Comment: I'd have thought it was better to work with PHP's AST, using something like [PHP_Parser](https://github.com/nikic/PHP-Parser) which was designed for precisely this type of use case

Comment: @karliwson Take the name of the variable.

Comment: @MarkBaker Oh, I did not know about PHP Parser. I'm taking a look.

Comment: Please clarify your question by providing a list of the different types of strings that you want to match and not match.  This will give your question context.

Comment: How would you like to handle these? `dosomething('string')`
`dosomething($variable)`
`lorem ipsum (but with this)`
`function(array $array1, array $array2)`
`function sum(...$numbers) {`
`function foo(?C $a){`
`call_user_func_array('increment', array(&$a));`
`function1 (function2 (function3(int $i)))`

Comment: I would first match the `dosomething\s*(` occurences, then use a parenthesis stack and character loopto find the ending parenthesis for each match .

Comment: @MarkBaker you should post this as an answer (preferably with a small example.)

Comment: @MarkBaker PHP_Parser worked perfectly!